# Convert °C to °F

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I'd like to convert °C to °F so I did this program but it doesn't work.

```js
function convertisseur() {
  var celsius = parseInt(document.getElementById("celsius").value);
  var fara = celsius * 1.8 + 32.0;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = celsius;
  document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = fara;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="formulaire">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Température en °C" id="celsius">
      <input type="submit" value="Valider" onclick="convertisseur()">
</form>

<p><span id="text"></span>°C équivaut à <span class="text2"></span>°F</p>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What's the question?

Comment: You are doing `document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML`, but no element with id text2 exists, so it gives an error (check your console). What you should be looking for is an element with a class of text2.

Comment: You're submitting your form. You're also trying to select an element by it's ID (`document.getElementById("text2")`) but you don't have one with that ID. You do have one with that *class* though `<span class="text2"></span>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three things:

1. You need to prevent the default behavior of the button to avoid form submission.
2. You need to modify the `span` with class `text2` because you actually want to add an id.
3. You need to pass the implicit object `event` as follow: `onclick="convertisseur(event)"`

```js
function convertisseur(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var celsius = parseInt(document.getElementById("celsius").value);
  var fara = celsius * 1.8 + 32.0;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = celsius;
  document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = fara;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="formulaire">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Température en °C" id="celsius">
  <input type="submit" value="Valider" onclick="convertisseur(event)">
</form>
</div>

<p><span id="text"></span>°C équivaut à <span id="text2"></span>°F</p>
```

I recommend you to embrace the function `addEventListener`

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', convertisseur);

function convertisseur(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var celsius = Number(document.getElementById("celsius").value);
  var fara = celsius * 1.8 + 32.0;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = celsius;
  document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = fara;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="formulaire">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Température en °C" id="celsius">
  <input id='button' type="submit" value="Valider">
</form>

<p><span id="text"></span>°C équivaut à <span id="text2"></span>°F</p>
```

Comment: For point 1 can you also repace `type="submit"` to `type="button"` would be better then prevent the default action. That means that you can skip point 3.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn yes, sure!

Answer (score 0):

I have update it check it
'text2' is class not an id so use **document.getElementsByClassName** to access it

```
 <form action="" class="formulaire">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Température en °C" id="celsius">
    <input type="button" value="Valider" onclick="convertisseur()">
 </form>

 function convertisseur() {
    var celsius = parseInt(document.getElementById("celsius").value);
    var fara = celsius * 1.8 + 32.0;
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = celsius;
    document.getElementsByClassName('text2')[0].innerHTML  = fara;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it doesn't work", it can be hard to tell what you mean. Try to be descriptive about the problem. Is anything showing when you load the HTML into a browser? What's the expected behavior, and what is happening instead? What have you tried in order to fix the problem?

From what I see here, I'll suggest that you should make sure you've included your JavaScript into your HTML correctly, either by

a) placing it between tags like so: `<script>Your code here.</script>`

or

b) including the script file in a src attribute like so: `<script src="script.js"></script>`

Otherwise, look over your HTML again and make sure all your opening tags that need a closing tag have one in the right place. And make sure you don't have any closing tags without an opening tag.